# push git repository from Azure Devops to remote centos server

Tags: ssh, centos, git, azure

I have a centos server where my git repository sits. I am able to connect to it from Azure Devops. Happy days. The real problems is pushing the changes from Azure Devops back to my original repository.

I've tried installing a Azure Devops agent, but all of the different ways, YAML, plugins (SSH), ect all have problems pushing back to my original repository for different reasons (Host key verification failed, timeout, or other)

Yes, I know i could easily pull from that Centos server, but i am trying to prevent the need to access that server via FTP or SSH.

All of the documents I keeping coming accross is for microsoft products or pushing to Github.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you able to push to the CentOS server from your own machine? If not, fix that first. Also what's stopping you from pulling from Azure and Pushing to CentOS yourself?

Comment: I can pull and push from my machine to the remote centos server no problem. I am trying to program something on the azure to trigger a push from azure to centos. That is the problem i need help with.

It's interesting, because all other providers (github, gitbucket etc.) seem to all want to push to each other, but not from their platform to the production server.

Comment: I'm not sure how you'd go about this but as a side note: git is not a (good) deployment tool as it lacks things such as permission management. Even if you are using git in that manner, as you mention the CentOS server being a production server, pulling from that server will also enable you to have a better way to schedule what happens. You might also be able to use a hook in order to trigger a deployment on your production server which would trigger the pull. Using the Azure agent would probably enable you to do the same. Might be worth it have a look why it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi Seth, thank you for your comments and feedback. Is there a better option to go about this. I want to have a way for our programmers to work and collaborate on code, but keep all parties out of the server.

Comment: What you're likely looking for is Continues Integration/Deployment it depends on your project and work structure. Also while git isn't a deployment tool, nothing is stopping you from building something to do it anyway. See for example [this](https://gitolite.com/deploy.html) but there are other solutions as well. I'm not familiar with the Azure Devops workflow but this might actually be tucked away in some place in there

Comment: Thanks so much Seth. It looks like I will need to look for a repository/ deployment / collaboration solution all built into one. Imagine if only the git applied the changes to the files and added any new files using the user and file permissions you chose. Seems simple enough